# Ansible: can I use a ssh key encrypted in the vault?

Tags: ansible

We have an ansible server setup with our ansible code stored in a git repos.  All the servers configured by ansible currently use the SSH key from our control server for access.  However I'd like to include the key in the ansible git repos instead (encrypted in the vault).  I'd like to do this as:

1) If our ansible server ever got compromised/had a unrecoverable hard drive failure/some other failure, we wouldn't have to generate a new ssh key and copy it to each ansible server before we could run ansible tasks again

2) It feels like it should be in the repos, as it's part of the setup/config to access the servers

3) We have other data stored in the vault and having to enter one password for the vault, and another for a SSH passphrase is a pain

We looked at coding a custom task to do this by creating a temporary file on disk, but it kind of feels like it should be something built in.  Also I like the way the built in decryption only holds files in ram.  The other issue was we couldn't find a method that would guaranteed to be run in the case of a failure, and so clean up the temporary file we created (kind of like an ensure block in programming)

Is there a safe way to use a vaulted ssh key?  Or failing that just a way to ask for the ssh passphrase upfront?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, each user should have their own private key which they use from the control server to access the deployment account. This way you can revoke someone's access much easier if they leave or no longer need access to run against servers. This also allows you to control which servers they run against.

To avoid being prompted for the SSH password every time use ssh-agent which caches the credentials in memory and avoids the prompt. I use this [startup script](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh) in my setup and it works well.

It's not good security practice to commit your credentials to your source code repository (although I've done it too). Backing up your user's home directories on the ansible server protects the private keys from hard drive failure.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I guess this is just a simple server with no other job than running ansible so we wanted to keep it as simple as possible especially as it's in the cloud (avoid backups etc etc).  We had actually gone with just the one shared account, although in hindsight I'm not sure why.  Anyways the ssh-agent trick will work well.  Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into using SSH agent forwarding. That way the developers/whoever keep their private keys private (on their trusted machines with no other user access) and then SSH to your control server and simply run Ansible from there. Your local ssh-agent should forward credentials across the control box to the remote nodes you are configuring.